Euclidification of quantum field theories and instantons
I have a question about the philosophy behind the concept of instantons. So far I know (following translation from German wiki instantons are spatially and temporary localised soliton solutions in "Euclidified" quantum field theories, specifically of Yang-Mills-equations after a Wick rotation for  Minkowski to Euclidean space.
I not have a good intuition for this sentence. What is the physical meaning of "Euclidification" of quantum field theory by means of such as Wick's transformation. Mathematically that's just a transformation, that's it, but what is it physical intuition?
In English version instantons are also described to be "classical solution to equations of motion". Here I'm confused, isn't the setting we consider intrinsically quantum mechanical? So which sense does it make to call them "classical solutions"?
Classical in which sense?
A naive guess: Does "classical" here in this context just pure formally mean for solutions which are obtained with respect to the equation after transformed via Wick transformation to Euclidean metric space. So these are solution in the "Euclidified" space, and that's we these called classical? Is it correct?
To put it in a nutshell, the main questions are:
(1): What is meant for viewpoint of physical intuition to "Euclidify" a quantum field theory.
(2): In which sense a instanton is a "classical" solution?

Instantons are saddle-points of the Euclidean path integral. Wick rotation means replacing time $t$ by imaginary time $i\tau$ such the the path integral measure changes from $\int DAe^{iS[A]}$ to $\int DAe^{-S[A]}$. Instantons occure not only in  Yang-Mills theory. The term originates from quantum mechanical tunneling, where two vacua of the system are seperated by a potential-well. If the potential has multiple vacua, the equations of motion become non-linear and admit non-trivial finite energy solutions.
$$\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}=-\frac{dV(\phi)}{d\phi}$$
An example is the double-well potential. Obviously the vacua are static solutions of the EOM but as I said there exist non-trivial finite energy solutions. Wick rotations means to revert the sign of the potential. It gets flipped on its head so to speak and the vacua are now maxima. The instanton now is understood as the trajectory of a particle which starts at one maximum rolling down the well on one side an up on the other side until it reaches the other maximum. The above equation can be transformed, using a virial theorem, to a seperable (one hopes) first order equation, which is much easier to solve $$\frac{d\phi}{d\tau}=\pm\sqrt{2V(\phi)}.$$ In the double-well potential on finds with a suitable choice of coordinates that $$\phi(\tau)=\pm\tanh(\tau),$$ which interpolates between the two minima of the potential $\phi_0=\pm1$ as $t$ goes to $\pm\infty$. So they are classical solutions, which are classical representations of a tunneling process. If you want to compute the transition amplitude, with say the path-integral, to go from one minimum to the other, the instanton will give you the main contribution in the semi-classical approximation. So we want the coupling constant to be small such that we can trust the approximation. It means that classical solutions are the main contributions. This corresponds to the situations where the vacua are seperated by a potential-well, which is fairly high. The computation of the amplitude boils down to the computation of determinants of Schrödinger operators, which describe the quantum fluctuations about the solutions. These have a zero-mode due to the translation invariance of the instanon and they have to be excluded and dealt with seperately. In Yang-Mills theory the one-instanton has 5 zero-modes. You then get the one-instanton contribution to the tunneling amplitude. The whole story includes also periodic instantons contributing to the path integral.
Although one-dimensional, the techniques to calculate the path integral are pretty much the same in Yang-Mills theory. You can also transform the Yang-Mills EOM into a first order system by the same trick as in one dimensions. These are the Yang-Mills instanton equations. Here Wick rotation  implies that the action is non-negative. So the instanton solution has to approach a flat or pure-gauge connection at infinity and its curvature is self-dual. One may also notice that the minima are topologically distinct. Meaning the semi-classical vacuum structure of Yang-Mills theory consists of topological sectors labeled by the integers. This originates from homotopy classes of maps between spheres but would lead us to far astray. In termporal gauge the instantons interpolate between the different topological sectors.
In conclusion instantons are classical non-trivial or topological solutions labeled by homotopy classes, which provide the main contribtuion to quantum mechanical tunneling amplitudes between topologically distinct vacua calculated in a semi-classical regime

Thank you for the detailed answer. Could you maybe give some details on how to see that $\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}=-\frac{dV(\phi)}{d\phi}$ transforms by means of virial theorem to $\frac{d\phi}{d\tau}=\sqrt{2V(\phi)}$? That appears to be surprising observation giving rise to nice simplification method on its own!

Also, could you maybe loose few words on what you in this context by "semi-classical" methods more precisely? Naive guess: Just collection of approaches where the involved quantities can be Taylor expanded in $\hbar$ as "small" parameter?
